# How to select tuple from rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have temp table that has following values:

```
╔═══════════╤═══════════╗
║ LATITUDE  │ LONGITUDE ║
╠═══════════╪═══════════╣
║ 69.122112 │ 39.122112 ║
╟───────────┼───────────╢
║ 69.123450 │ 39.123450 ║
╚═══════════╧═══════════╝
```

I want to do something like this

```
with temp as (select LATITUDE,LONGITUDE from SOME_TABLE_B)
select * from temp
union
select LATITUDE,LONGITUDE from SOME_TABLE where (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) in (select (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) from temp)
```

So as to select all other data that has similar latitude and longitude pair. But I get the following result:

> ORA-00920 invalid relational operator

**How can I select tuple from table, to use IN CLAUSE with tuple?**

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is the additional parentheses in the subquery.  Try this:

```
select LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
from SOME_TABLE
where (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) in (select LATITUDE, LONGITUDE from temp)
```

Comment: You are right, that parentheses what broke the query. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure about your requirement. If you want to check the data availability in temp table you can use below query,

```
select LATITUDE,LONGITUDE from SOME_TABLE where (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) in (select 
LATITUDE, LONGITUDE from temp)
```

If you want to check avaliablity as well as union the data from temp, you can use below,

```
select LATITUDE,LONGITUDE from SOME_TABLE where (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) in (select 
LATITUDE, LONGITUDE from temp)
UNION
select 
LATITUDE, LONGITUDE from temp
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you could also try using a join with a subquery:

```
select LATITUDE,LONGITUDE 
from SOME_TABLE  s 
INNER JOIN  ( 
    select  LATITUDE, LONGITUDE 
 from temp
 ) t on t.LATITUDE = s.LATITUDE 
    AND t.LONGITUDE  = s.LONGITUDE
```